# PHP - Timed MySQLi Row Update?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, row, timed

I was wondering whether or not this was possible to do.
Would there be a way using PHP to update the value of a row every 24 hours. Why?
I'm creating a kids website that uses online currency, known as Yads. The value of the Row is the amount of Yads the user has. Every 24 hours the amount of Yads will be increased by 20.

I would like to know if that is possible using MySQL Queries?

EXTRA INFO:
Table: Users
Row name: Yads
I'm using MySqli queries.

Thanks.

Comment: Use a cron job to run a script every 24 hours?

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can, read about [Event Scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html) or write your script and add it to the schedule on the server.

**Event scheduler example:**

```
CREATE EVENT event_name
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY '1' DAY
    STARTS '2013-01-27 12:00:00'
    DO
       -- your statements
    END
```

Comment: @Buddy Log, does this answer your question? If so, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want PHP to do this, the answer is YES, but you must do it by using `cron` or the alike to execute your PHP in a desired schedule. Hope it helps.